# Contador de sugestões de edição está incoerente

Tags: bug, status-intencional, notificações, edições-sugeridas

O contador laranja que indica o número de edições sugeridas pendentes ficou maluco, está marcando alguma outra coisa. Ou é cache?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho visto isso ocorrer intermitentemente, e tenho certeza de que não é o cache do meu browser (testei em diversas máquinas).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Descobri que **não é bug**. O comportamento do indicador laranja foi alterado, e agora ele lista a soma de todas as análises pendentes<strike>, exceto as da fila de fechamento</strike> (exceto no SO em inglês, onde a fila de *close votes* não conta).

Tem ainda as seguintes pegadinhas:

- Precisa haver pelo menos 10 análises pendentes para o indicador aparecer (estranho, pois aqui no SOpt aparece com menos)
- O valor mostrado no indicador fica em cache, então pode marcar um número incorreto.
- Posts que estão na fila de análise mas não se aplicam a você (por exemplo, uma pergunta em que você já votou para reabrir) também são contados

Esses pontos são meio estranhos, talvez esse indicador ainda sofra alguns ajustes.

---

<sup>**Fonte: [Resposta da Anna Lear♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/167534) a [Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar)
(no MSE; veja também os comentários abaixo da resposta)**</sup>

Comment: valeu pela resposta, tava achando que meu browser tava louco

Comment: agora ele sumiu totalmente para mim, e tem uma análise em baixa qualidade e uma primeira publicação

Comment: agora voltou a aparecer, mas só aparece o numero 3 para mim, será que o nosso mínimo é 3?

Comment: O mínimo é 1, aparece-me sempre no mínimo com 1 em fila. Acho que o mínimo de 10 no SOEN tem a sua lógica, vendo a dimensão de cada site...

Comment: Eu colocaria isso como "status-buggy-bydesign" ao invés de "status-bydesign". Esse comportamento atual simplesmente não tem sentido.