# Histórico de análises mostrando atividade de outros usuários

Tags: suporte, status-intencional

Eu não sei se estou falando "besteira", mas inicialmente (ao menos no StackOVerflow em Inglês) o [**Review History**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) mostra apenas as minhas atividades:

[image: historico de analise do StackOverflow em Ingles]

Porém ao acessar hoje o [**Histórico de análises**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) do StackOverflow em Português percebi que está aparecendo todas aprovações e rejeições feitas por outros usuários:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto está certo? Tem como eu "filtrar" para visualizar apenas as minhas atividades ou isto é um BUG?

Outro "problema" relatado, que acredito fazer parte disto, no top-bar sempre aparece quando existe analises disponíveis (uma espécie de "push"), porém ao acessar o [link de review](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) todos estão com "0", ou seja não há analises a serem feitas, mas continua aparecendo os "pushs" com "5" analises:

[image: pushs do stackoverflow]

E mesmo que eu acesse todas páginas de analises, no top-bar sempre fica marcando "5 analises".

Eu sei que parece "loucura" ou estou tendo a impressão errada, mas faz alguns dias que o StackOverflow em Português parece estar tendo alguns "BUGs", eu sei que alguns argumentos seria é o CACHE, mas realmente eu não notei tais situações em nenhuma das outras comunidades (apesar que só frequento SOen e SOpt com mais frequência).

Realmente isto me parece algum BUG.

Comment: O 2º caso é devido ao cache que demora mais do que deveria, por isso sempre marca *X analises* mesmo não tendo nenhuma. Já houve uma questão sobre isso por aqui. [**Aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1282/contador-de-sugest%C3%B5es-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-incoerente/1284#1284) está a questão sobre o cache.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Obrigado! Então eu pensei (ainda penso) que estavam relacionados pois começaram no mesmo instante, notei que os "pushs" (posso chama-los assim?) não sumiam então fui analisar o histórico e me deparei com o primeiro problema.

Comment: Sobre o histórico, creio que seja isso mesmo e para ver o *seu* histórico, basta rolar até o final e clicar em **my review history**.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Deu certo, acho que estou entendendo, eu atingi a pontuação para ter acesso as ferramentas semelhantes aos dos moderadores recentemente (2,000 pontos), então acho que eu posso ver as atividades dos colegas. Desculpe a confusão.

Comment: Pode ser por isso que não via antes, e no SO-EN a reputação deve ser mais alta, por isso também não vê.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme o @PapaCharlie o segundo problema é uma questão de CACHE, que é explicado **[nesta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1284/3635)**.

O primeiro problema (visualizar histórico dos demais usuários) é por causa da minha recente graduação dentro do StackOverflow em Português devido ter atingido recentemente os 2,000 pontos (está informação se refere a beta, hoje estamos graduados e a pontuação para atualmente é 10,000), conforme o [**Central de ajuda** > **Privilégios** > **Acesso Às Ferramentas Do Moderador**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) eu agora tenho acesso ao *histórico completo de revisões por todos os usuários em qualquer /fila de revisão*

No SOen a pontuação para esta graduação é bem maior e por isto eu não tenho o acesso lá.

### Lista dos privilégios "adicionais"

Estes privilégios são adquiridos a partir dos 2,000 nas sites/comunidades beta e 10,000 pontos nas sites/comunidades graduadas:

- Publicações com votos extremos
- Publicações com o maior número de comentários/visualizações/edições
- Perguntas recentemente protegidas
- Perguntas recentemente encerradas/reabertas
- Perguntas recentemente migradas
- Publicações recentemente excluídas/com exclusão cancelada
- Perguntas com votos pelo encerramento/reabertura pendentes
- Publicações com votos de exclusão/cancelamento de exclusão pendentes
- Novas respostas para perguntas antigas
- Estatística de edições sugeridas
- Estatística de feedback anônimo
- O histórico completo de revisões por *todos* os usuários em qualquer **[/fila de revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)**

Comment: Nota: nosso site deve graduar em breve, então a pontuação necessária para ver esse histórico vai subir (acho que para 10k, como no SO).